# PHP won't run on Fedora 15

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fedora, httpd, selinux

I have followed [this exact tutorial](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) on installing php on a Fedora 15 system.

I have all the necessary packages installed with no errors. Yet the simple phpinfo() test page will show - it will show a blank page. When I try to see the source, I see it downloaded my .php file as plain text and loaded it in the browser.

So I am guessing for some reason php module is not loaded in httpd. Does anyone have any idea why?

P.S. I am really hoping SELinux this time has nothing to do with this!

Comment: Sift through your Apache error logs to see if it's reporting anything. `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: Also, as silly as it sounds, paste your index.php file in your post.

Comment: Check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` if you expect SELinux.

Comment: Index.php: <? phpinfo(); ?>
SELinux - permissive mode (setenforce 0). Some key items in the error log after server restart: (1) SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 (2) [Sun Apr 08 09:19:55 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with SELinux. To narrow it down, check to see if it's even turned on:

`selinuxenabled && echo enabled || echo disabled`

If it's turned on, temporarily disable it with:

`echo 0 > /selinux/enforce`

SELinux will be enabled after a reboot, or until you manually enable it:

`echo 1 > /selinux/enforce`

Comment: Thank you, I tried that - it did not make a change. I believe there is a configuration problem in httpd.conf or somewhere, a search for 'php' in httpd.conf returns nothing despite having all the packages needed.